# Node.js Map Object Causes Memory Leak

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I wrote a online chat site with nodejs and I'm using map objects to keep track of online users.

```
    const onlineUsers = new Map();
    const userRoomList = new Map();
    const userIpList = new Map();
```

```
function addClientToMap(username, status = 'vis'){
    if(!onlineUsers.has(username)){
        onlineUsers.set(username, status)
    }
}

function addUserIpList(username, ip){
    if(!userIpList.has(username)){
        userIpList.set(username, ip)
    }
}

function removeClientFromMap(username, socketId){
    if(onlineUsers.has(username)){
        onlineUsers.delete(username);
        userRoomList.delete(username);
    }
}
```

I'm storing the usernames of users but they are causing memory leak. So I need a better alternative. What other methods there are that I can store online user data ?

Comment: what you mean by memory leak? You are getting the maximum heap size? You are using a tool or method to detect the are occurring a memory leak?

Comment: @lukaswilkeer My cpu usage rises to 100% and then i'm not able to connect to site until i restart it there is no error in the logs.

Comment: You need to do more targeted debugging to know that this particular code is causing a memory leak.  CPU usage rising to 100% could be many things.  The usual way to diagnose possible memory leaks is with heap snapshots.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid memory leak, you need to store your users in socket.room if you use sockets, if you use long pooling, store users in your database.

Comment: Okey but if i use database to store my online clients wouldn't it be time consuming ? because then every time when i want to add someone or delete someone or get the online user list i have to run queries on db ?

Comment: use socket.io for this. This library is doing all instead you. If you use this library you will not have to use a database ;)